# In reverse engineering, what does it mean to "patch a file"?

Tags: patching, patch-reversing, crackme

I've been solving some crackmes, and every file that I download, in the "instructions" says: "Patching is obviously not allowed". What does that mean? And how does one patch a file?

Comment: In simple term, patching is as same as editing a file.

Comment: Hi and welcome to RE.SE. Given the context, I guess the idea is to no allow "cheating" by making ones cracking job easier using well-established techniques? I am not sure how to interpret it, though. Is patching not allowed in the executable image on disk? Not anywhere? What about automated kinds of instrumentation or techniques such as hooking, `LD_PRELOAD` and friends? ...

Comment: @0xC0000022L generally it means a submitted solution to the crackme challenge that relies on patching (static file modification) won't be accepted by the crackme author. I think DLL injection and such usually is ok unless specifically stated by the crackme author that it isn't. (I've had a lot of success using `LD_PRELOAD`)

Comment: To OP, can you share the crackme link?

Comment: @julian yep, that was my point regarding `LD_PRELOAD` - it's _soooo_ useful for these things. Thanks for the further explanation.

Comment: @Biswapriyo you can google and find upcoming CTFs and participate with tons of crackmes.

Comment: @0xC0000022L No problem, and your right, `LD_PRELOAD` is a beautiful thing. I forgot to mention that the reason it is usually acceptable is that if DLL injection is something the crackme author is concerned about, they will provide a statically-linked binary rather than saying "No LD_PRELOAD".

Comment: @Biswapriyo Hi, I've been downloading crackmes [here!](https://crackmes.one/) Most of them you'll see that the author doesn't want answers that relly on patching! Sorry for the delay in my answer tho

Answer (score 3):

Following quote comes from [unix.stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17553/meaning-of-patching-binary-files):

> To patch a file means to modify it, with the connotation that the modification is generally small.

So, patching the executable is a process of changing its content usually performed for changing its original behaviour.

*Patching is obviously not allowed* means that the author of a particular crackme wants you to crack it without modifying its content. For instance, consider a simple program:

```
ask_user_for_password();
read_input();
if (isPasswordCorrect())
    printf(“Congratulations, you have cracked it!\n”);
else
    printf(“Wrong password! Try again!\n”);
```

Of course one can patch it so that it always prints the *"Congratulations [...]"* message, but the point of this very simple crackme is to actually *find* that password somehow (by finding decryption key for example).

Generally, to patch a file, you want to:

1. Find the place / instruction you want to change (it may be `jnz` to `jz` as @Axel Munoz said, but it may be a `jmp` to the location containing the code you want to be executed as well).
2. Find out what is the *machine code* representing the instruction you want to put there - it can be done by first compiling the program written in assembly and then disassembling it. If you are working on x86 architecture, you can use [this site](https://defuse.ca/online-x86-assembler.htm) as well.
3. Open the binary in a *hex editor*, find the offset where you want to put your code and just paste the machine code you obtained in the previous step.

Answer (score -1):

The term "patching a [binary]" means to modify the instruction set. For example if there is a conditional jump that requires some memory to be set to a specific value, instead of modifying the memory, which might be the objective of the crackme, I could simply patch the binary to always take that jump (either by changing the condition of the jump from `jnz` to `jz`). Patching through a debugger easily allows me to change the instruction, save the new binary, and then run it.

[Here is some more info.](https://oalabs.openanalysis.net/2017/10/22/quick-and-dirty-binary-patching-with-ida-and-a-hex-editor/)

Comment: You are pretty inaccurate by saying that patching means modifying instruction set, but link is good.

Comment: I honestly never understood the point of _inverting_ the condition (`jnz` to `jz`). It seems odd to change one conditional jump into another conditional jump when an altogether unconditional jump exists ...

Comment: @0xC0000022L It may be useful when there is a bug in the program and you want to invert an if-else block for example to fix it. But I agree it’s rather rare case.

Comment: @Croll I agree it's not the best way to phrase, how would you put it?

Comment: patching is a synonym/slang to modifying binary contents, both on disk and in memory, i guess.

Comment: I know what you mean (modifying code/logic in the binary), but "instruction set" refers to the set of instructions recognized by a CPU and is tied together with CPU architecture. For example the x86 instruction set is different from the MIPS instruction set